# passing title: @title.id parameter in controller's view A, so controller B could find @title = Title.find(params[:title])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Title view I want to pass title.id via link_to, so that in controller Sessions I could retrieve it. However, I always get "could not find Title without an ID". I have tried many scenarios and closest, probably would be:

titles/new.html.erb

```
       <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in", title: @title.id %>
```

routes.rb

```
       get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
       def create
       @title = Title.find(params[:title])
       redirect_to new_title_order_url(@title) #here I also have nested resources with Order
       end
```

Should I pass title.id in another way or it possible as I explained?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass them as parameters by just using "/auth/facebook?title=..." but that's not the Rails way to do it. What you should be doing is defining your routes so that you can say

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", facebook_auth_path(title: title.id) %>.
```

See [Rails Routing.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook?#{ {id: "sign_in", title: @title.id}.to_query }" %>
```

However you should probably convert your route into named route:

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', as: :auth
```

And then:

```
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", auth_path('facebook', id: 'sign_in', title: @title.id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In

`<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in", title: @title.id %>`

`id: "sign_in", title: @title.id`: these two will only be added as an option to link_to(anchor tag). They will not be passed with your GET request `/auth/facebook`.

So accessing params[:title] will always give nil in your case. Hence, the error.

If you want to pass params, check [omniauth-facebook official doc](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring)

For Example: (Change it as per your requirement)

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
           :scope => 'email,user_birthday,read_stream', :display => 'popup'
end
```

If you want to set the display format, auth_type, or scope on a per-request basis, you can just pass it to the OmniAuth request phase URL, for example: `/auth/facebook?display=popup` or `/auth/facebook?scope=email`.

Comment: can I pass them as parameters?

Comment: Are you using omniauth-facebook gem?